# Increase vertical space in svg text

Tags: css, svg

Following is the jsfiddle I have tried

http://jsfiddle.net/C27Sw/

Please make sure that you need to scroll the output to see the content in jsfiddle

What I want is to add vertical spacing between those texts with css,Is it possible?

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800px" height="400px" 
    style="position: relative; display: block; left: -0.09090423583984375px; top: -0.8068084716796875px;"><g><path style="display: block; " 
    d="M714 170 790 170 790 225 714 225 z" stroke="" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="square"
    stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#a8c6fa"></path>
    <text id="k10002" data-model-id="k10016" x="734" y="187" fill-opacity="1" 
    style="font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; cursor: pointer;" fill="#000">Extracted</text>
    <text id="k10015" data-model-id="k10014" x="734" y="202" fill-opacity="1" 
    style="font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; cursor: pointer;" fill="#000">Mapped</text>
    <text id="k10013" data-model-id="k10012" x="734" y="217" fill-opacity="1" 
    style="font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; cursor: pointer;" fill="#000">Validated</text>
    <path style="display: block; cursor: pointer;" data-model-id="k10016" 
    d="M719.5 179.5 727.5 179.5 727.5 186.5 719.5 186.5 z" stroke="#00a4d3" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#00a4d3"></path>
    <path style="display: block; cursor: pointer;" data-model-id="k10014" 
    d="M719.5 194.5 727.5 194.5 727.5 201.5 719.5 201.5 z" stroke="#ffa834" 
    stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" 
    stroke-opacity="1" fill="#ffa834"></path><path style="display: block; cursor: pointer;"
     data-model-id="k10012" d="M719.5 209.5 727.5 209.5 727.5 216.5 719.5 216.5 z" 
    stroke="#72bb53" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" 
    fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#72bb53"></path></g></svg>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you may want to provide more info in the question, and not just a link - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: @SW4 the following is the output i have tried..stackoverflow doesnt recommend closing questions which I have tried..

Comment: You need to show what you've tried by supplying code within the question body itself and not simply with a link, this is because SO aims to be a self contained resource for future users and not reliant on external resources for context

Comment: You can't do it with CSS except by making the font smaller.

Comment: @SW4 i have edited the qs..is this what u want..which i feel was meaningless to paste so i didn't add atfirst

Answer (score 1):

First of all svg is not working on screen pixel system. It is working with co-ordinate system.
It obeys the path and other co-ordinate attributes we specify.

So don't try to do it via css. But you can increase the spacing always by changing the path attributes.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800px" height="400px" style="position: relative; display: block; left: -0.09090423583984375px; top: -0.8068084716796875px;">
    <g>
        <path style="display: block; " d="M714 170 790 170 790 245 714 245 z" stroke="" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#a8c6fa"></path>
        <text id="k10002" data-model-id="k10016" x="734" y="187" fill-opacity="1" style="font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; cursor: pointer;" fill="#000">Extracted</text>
        <text id="k10015" data-model-id="k10014" x="734" y="212" fill-opacity="1" style="font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; cursor: pointer;" fill="#000">Mapped</text>
        <text id="k10013" data-model-id="k10012" x="734" y="237" fill-opacity="1" style="font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; cursor: pointer;" fill="#000">Validated</text>
        <path style="display: block; cursor: pointer;" data-model-id="k10016" d="M719.5 179.5 727.5 179.5 727.5 186.5 719.5 186.5 z" stroke="#00a4d3" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#00a4d3"></path>
        <path style="display: block; cursor: pointer;" data-model-id="k10014" d="M719.5 204.5 727.5 204.5 727.5 211.5 719.5 211.5 z" stroke="#ffa834" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#ffa834"></path>
        <path style="display: block; cursor: pointer;" data-model-id="k10012" d="M719.5 229.5 727.5 229.5 727.5 236.5 719.5 236.5 z" stroke="#72bb53" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#72bb53"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**[Play your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/C27Sw/2/)**.

Check for the differences in the svg markup.

Comment: ...:)..Here the path is dynamically generated so the only possible option is to change it from js or css.Is it possible?

Comment: Try js solution. Can u post the js source code for building the svg. I think we can tweak that